# (n*2-1)%p: avoiding the use of 64 bits when n and p are 32 bits

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, math, modulus

Consider the following function:

```
inline unsigned int f(unsigned int n, unsigned int p) 
{
    return (n*2-1)%p;
}
```

Now suppose that `n` (and `p`) are greater than `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

For example `f(4294967295U, 4294967291U)`.

The mathematical result is `7` but the function will return `2`, because `n*2` will overflow.

Then the solution is simple: we just have to use 64 bits integer instead. Assuming that the declaration of the function has to stay the same:

```
inline unsigned int f(unsigned int n, unsigned int p) 
{
    return (static_cast<unsigned long long int>(n)*2-1)%p;
}
```

Everything is fine. At least in principle. The problem is that this function will be called millions of times in my code (I mean the overflowing version), and 64 bits modulus is way slower than the 32 bits version (see [here](http://nicolas.limare.net/pro/notes/2014/12/12_arit_speed/) for example).

The question is the following: is there any trick (mathematical or algorithmic) to avoid to execute a 64 bits version of the modulus operation. And what would be a new version of `f` using this trick? (keeping the same declaration).

- Note 1: `n > 0`
- Note 2: `p > 2`
- Note 3: `n` can be lower than `p`: `n=4294967289U`, `p=4294967291U`
- Note 4: the less the number of modulus operation used, the better (3 32 bits modulo is too large, 2 is interesting, and 1 will surely outperform)
- Note 5: of course the result will be processor dependent. Assume a use on the lasts supercomputers with the last xeon available.

Comment: You should use a better example though, otherwise you'll get cheap answers that exploit that `n` is not pre-reduced

Comment: Why not compromise? Do a 64-bit modulus only if the answer could overflow (I.e. if n > 0x80000000). If you don't call it with big `n` often, then this will work well.

Comment: @nneonneo: I added a remark in the post, and the function will often be called with big `n`.

Comment: By the way are you open to an answer in x86 assembly? You can side-step most of this problem there because a 32bit modulo really takes a 64bit divided (subject to some restraints, but it works out here if `p > 1` and `n != 0`)

Comment: @harold I'm open to assembly (but if you give and example, the code has to compile in g++)

Comment: Notice that this is going to be extremely processor-dependent... I threw together a quick benchmark using some of the methods below (even if they are flawed, just to understand if the additional complexity is more costly than the 64-bit operations). On my old Phenom II 955 just doing the calculations in 64 bit is even slightly better than 32 bit; switching to 64 bit if n*2 would overflow costs ~20% more, doing (n%p + n%p) costs twice. OTOH, on a recent i7, if 32 bit takes 1, 64 bit takes 2, checking the high bit costs 2.2, doing (n%p + n%p) costs 1.4.

Comment: @Vincent: I suspect you should be profiling different options. Drop in a 64-bit modulus and see if it is actually slower than some of the options below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I dislike dealing with AT&T syntax and GCC's "extended asm constraints", I think this works (it worked in my, admittedly limited, tests)

```
uint32_t f(uint32_t n, uint32_t p)
{
    uint32_t res;
    asm (
      "xorl %%edx, %%edx\n\t"
      "addl %%eax, %%eax\n\t"
      "adcl %%edx, %%edx\n\t"
      "subl $1, %%eax\n\t"
      "sbbl $0, %%edx\n\t"
      "divl %1"
      : "=d"(res)
      : "S"(p), "a"(n)
      : 
      );
  return res;
}
```

The constraints may be unnecessarily strict or wrong, I don't know. It seemed to work.

The idea here is to do a regular 32bit division, which actually takes a 64bit dividend. It only works if the quotient will fit in 32 bits (otherwise overflow is signaled), which is always true under the circumstances (`p` at least 2, `n` not zero). The stuff before the division handles the times 2 (with overflow into `edx`, the "high half"), then the "subtract 1" with potential borrow. The `"=d"` output thing makes it take the remainder as result. `"a"(n)` puts `n` in `eax` (letting it choose an other register doesn't help, the division will take an input in `edx:eax` anyway). `"S"(p)` could probably be `"r"(p)` (seems to work) but I'm not sure enough to trust it.

Comment: Is there a way to store the result in n instead of res avoiding an unecessary assignment or not? + could you explain what "S"(d) means?

Comment: @Vincent maybe but that doesn't really avoid anything, there's no memory write or anything like that, just a `movl %edx, %eax` to return it. "S"(d) puts d in esi (it's already there) edit: oh wait, it was `p`. Well whatever, it puts p in esi then.

Answer (score 3):

We know that `p` is less than `max`, then `n % p` is less than max. They are both unsigned, that means that `n % p`  is positive, and smaller than `p`. Unsigned overflow is well-defined, so if `n % p * 2` exceeds `p`, we can compute it as `n % p - p + n % p`, which will not overflow, so together it will look like this:

```
unsigned m = n % p;
unsigned r;
if (p - m < m) // m * 2 > p
    r = m - p + m;
else // m * 2 <= p
    r = m * 2;

// subtract 1, account for the fact that r can be 0
if (r == 0) r = p - 1;
else r = r - 1;
return r % p;
```

Note that you can avoid the last modulus, because we know that `r` doesn't exceed `p * 2` (it is at most `m * 2`, and `m` doesn't exceed `p`), so the last line can be rewritten as

```
return r >= p ? r - p : r
```

Which brings the number of modulus operations to 1.

Comment: "64-bit integers should not be slower than 32 bit integers on 64 bit platform."  This is just not true when talking about division.

Comment: agree with both comments above, edited the post, since it was irrelevant to my answer anyway

Comment: I wonder how `r = m - p + m` is evaluated. `m - p` is below zero, so doesn't this results in an overflow since `r` is unsigned? I'm not familiar with c++.

Comment: Yes, `m - p` does result in an intentional underflow, but underflow of unsigned integers is well-defined. Adding `m` will overflow back, because `m + m` is at least as big as `p` in that branch.

Comment: Ah nice. I didn't know that it overflows back. Nice idea.

Comment: Note that by using `((n-1)*2+1)%p` instead of `(n*2-1)%p`, you can save one conditional. Don't know if it would be faster though.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, this version seems to be avoid any overflows:

```
std::uint32_t f(std::uint32_t n, std::uint32_t p) 
{
    auto m = n%p;
    if (m <= p/2) {
        return (m==0)*p+2*m-1;
    }
    return p-2*(p-m)-1;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ed87617e9e618e0). The idea is that if an overflow would occur in `2*m-1`, we can work with `p-2*(p-m)-1`, which avoids this by multiplying `2` with the modular additive inverse instead.

Comment: That will potentially fail for p greater than half the maximum that the type can represent, as (n%p)*2 can still overflow.

Comment: Only in that example. Flip `n` and `p`... so that `n%p == n`.

Comment: @Peter It seems the code is correct now, any overflows in sight?

Comment: @Columbo The idea is correct. But there are a couple of minor details. `f(0, ...)` returns `p - 1`, while the original function returns `((ulong)-1) % p`. Also, if `m == p/2`, we get `(uint)-1`.

Comment: @AlexD The first part is **intended**. -1 is equivalent to p-1 modulo p. But yeah, I knew there was an issue with the latter, and I fixed it. How about now?

Comment: @Columbo Looks good. Regarding the first part. I have to say that I find your interpretation of `-1 mod p` most logical. However, there are [other interpretations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). And C++ `%`-operator works differently. Moreover, -1 assumes _signed_ int, while we deal with _unsigned_ (leading to underflow). Anyway, +1 :-).